# Titanium Alloy Pull-to-refresh widget not scrolling properly on Android devices

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, pull-to-refresh, titanium-modules, titanium-widgets

I am working on Titanium SDK and need to implement that [Pull-To-Refresh](https://github.com/jolicode/Alloy-PullToRefresh) widget. This widget works perfect while on iOS devices but when I try to run the same on Android devices, it doesn't even scroll the controller.

I have placed code on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrEZRw3ujafOUxzVkJTREx1MkE/edit?usp=sharing).

Let me know if anyone has used this and encountered the same issue.

Comment: The issue might be resolved if I use ActionBar style progress bar as seen in Google mails. This will show just single line to indicate refresh. Can anyone post link for this in Alloy widget?

Comment: We opted for another solution as there was issue with this widget.